# Restart all running builds when Jenkins restarts

Tags: jenkins, deployment, restart

Due to performance issues we hard restart our jenkins master and mesos slaves every night at 2am. However, some jobs that we run have tests that can run for hours, and if they hit that 2AM mark, the jobs stop and are lost until bring ran again the next day.

Is there a plugin or solution that can detect that job(s) are running, and be triggered to try them again after jenkins master restarts?

Comment: How are you restarting your jenkins master server? It is via cron? A configuration management tool? Jenkins?!

Comment: It's via Jenkins with the DSL plugin.

Comment: Is this something that requires a reboot of the entire master server? Or just the Jenkins service?

Comment: It does require a reboot of the entire master server which is just hosted on a container